# Populating a form with a dropdown - Access

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to create a form in access that has a dropdown at the top and will populate the rest of the form with the record that corresponds to what is chosen.

I have looked at 2 different guides online but both point to older versions of Access and I think I am missing something.

So. The order that I did everything:

1. I went to the table for the form. And I clicked Form. This made a quick form with all of the fields as text boxes.
2. I deleted the field that will be the dropdown and I put in a dropdown canceling the wizard
3. In the data section for the dropdown. I edited "Row Source" to select the field that will be in the dropdown and the unique ID, in that order.
4. I set the bound Column to 2 (I have tried both)
5. I set the name of the Combo Box to "TitleSelector"
6. In Form Settings. For "Record Source". I have "[forms]![Edit Piece].[TitleSelector] & "*" in Criteria for "ID". I also have the rest of the fields in the Query listed
7. I added the "me.requery" to on change
   Not sure if it means anything. When I was typing in the Criteria for "ID" it did not show "TitleSelector" in the drop down.

I am using Access 2010

Edit:
My Problem -
The dropdown itself shows everything correctly. However nothing happens when I choose something

Edit:

```
SELECT Pieces.ID, Pieces.Title, Pieces.Composer, Pieces.Instrumentation, Pieces.Location, Pieces.Location_2
FROM Pieces
WHERE (((Pieces.ID)=[forms]![Edit Piece].[TitleSelector]));
```

Edit:
Here is a link to a copy of my database: https://www.dropbox.com/s/tpnqm686tj653fg/Trisha%20Database.accdb

Comment: If you open the Immediate window (Ctrl+g) after opening the form and making a selection in the combo, and type `? [forms]![Edit Piece].[TitleSelector]` and press enter ... what value does the Immediate window show you?

Comment: If I take out the & "*", when I open the form it asks for a parameter. I did what you asked. And it gave me "2" which is the ID for the one chosen.

Comment: Something doesn't sound right there to me.  I thought you're using a SELECT query as your form's record source.  Please edit that query, switch to SQL View, copy the SQL text and paste it into your question.  (You don't have to save any changes when you edit the query.)

Comment: SELECT Pieces.ID, Pieces.Title, Pieces.Composer, Pieces.Instrumentation, Pieces.Location, Pieces.Location_2
FROM Pieces
WHERE (((Pieces.ID)=[forms]![Edit Piece].[TitleSelector]));

Comment: I can't spot anything wrong with that query, Jon.  However, I also don't see that `& "*"` you mentioned.  I'm just more lost now.

Comment: I had edited that out. Maybe there is something I am missing. I uploaded the database to dropbox https://www.dropbox.com/s/tpnqm686tj653fg/Trisha%20Database.accdb

Comment: Rats!  I'm using Access 2007 which complains "unrecognized database format" with that accdb.  Maybe @GordThompson will have a peak ...

Comment: @HansUp I would have looked at this sooner but for some reason the `@` reference didn't show up in my Inbox. Sorry.... :(

Answer (score 2):

Adding the me.requery to the ON CHANGE EVENT 
(select CODE BUILDER - and enter the me.requery there) should work.

Comment: Just tried that. Still does not work. I added a link to the database (before the change you suggested) https://www.dropbox.com/s/tpnqm686tj653fg/Trisha%20Database.accdb

Answer (score 1):

I have downloaded the sample file. Your problem is that the `Record Source` for the [Edit Piece] form is set to...

```
SELECT Pieces.ID, Pieces.Title, Pieces.Composer, Pieces.Instrumentation, Pieces.Location, Pieces.Location_2 FROM Pieces WHERE (((Pieces.ID)=[forms]![Edit Piece].[TitleSelector] & "*"));
```

...and the `& "*"` at the very end is causing the query to return no records. Removing that last bit so the Form's `Record Source` is...

```
SELECT Pieces.ID, Pieces.Title, Pieces.Composer, Pieces.Instrumentation, Pieces.Location, Pieces.Location_2 FROM Pieces WHERE (((Pieces.ID)=[forms]![Edit Piece].[TitleSelector]));
```

...gets your form working.

### Edit

To have your form display information from the related tables (instead of just the foreign key values from the [Pieces] table), change the `Record Source` of the Form from...

```
SELECT Pieces.ID, Pieces.Title, Pieces.Composer, Pieces.Instrumentation, Pieces.Location, Pieces.Location_2 FROM Pieces WHERE (((Pieces.ID)=[forms]![Edit Piece].[TitleSelector]));
```

...to...

```
SELECT Pieces.ID, Pieces.Title, Composer.Composer, Instrumentation.Instrumentation, Location.Location, Location_1.Location AS Location_2 FROM (Location INNER JOIN (Instrumentation INNER JOIN (Composer INNER JOIN Pieces ON Composer.ID = Pieces.Composer) ON Instrumentation.ID = Pieces.Instrumentation) ON Location.ID = Pieces.Location) INNER JOIN Location AS Location_1 ON Pieces.Location_2 = Location_1.ID WHERE (((Pieces.ID)=[forms]![Edit Piece].[TitleSelector]));
```

Comment: Thank you, I am not entirely sure why that did not work the first time I tried that. Do you know how I can replace those text fields with dropdowns that show the value from the other table (instead of showing the ID for Composer it would show the name) ? I am stuck at just trying to make it show the ID. The rest of the fields update but that field does not change.