# Using a query to fill in form data

Tags: forms

I am a newbie with access 2010.  I have built a test database to try things out.  I have a form: Rec_Pay with a field IncomeSource which is on the main form as a combobox.  When I select the text "Business" I want it to automatically open another form and fill in all the information from the main form without mehaving to type it again, is this possible.  Help if you can

Answer (score 0):

You must Describe Detail what do you need, and what issue?
have you try with query builder and form editor/design?, you can use onchange event on your combobox.. and then filled query SQL

```
`SELECT .. FROM ... WHERE ..= your combobox data`
```

on the event form load you need to fill

Maybe this link would help [Populating a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16738124/populating-a-form-with-a-dropdown-access)

and this

[Fill Form using combo drop down](http://www.creativeconnections.co.uk/index.php/microsoft-access/172-how-to-fill-an-access-form-field-by-using-a-combo-box-dropdown-list)

Hope this help,